# Linking views with controllers in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I created a Sign Up form as below. Can someone guide me as to how to link this view with the controller. I am using RoR as the framework. In ror they have a way of creating forms using <% f.text_field....%> which they will directly use in the controller. But since here i don't have such fields how should I proceed?

I made a similar post and asked about routing where a user suggested that I go through the documentations. I had already gone through some documentation but I found some of them to be confusing. Since the user asked to do so, I tried going through again but failed at understanding how to go forward.

If someone can guide me towards a starting point I will be utterly grateful as I am on a tight schedule.

P.S: I am new to RoR, hence the stupid questions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
    <main>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <form class=" " action="/users/create" method="post">

<h3>Sign Up </h3>  

<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s12 m6 l6">
 <input id="user_name" name="user_name" type="text" class="validate">
<label for="user_name">User Name</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row ">
<div class="input-field col s5">
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="validate">
<label for="password">Password</label>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col s10">
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light  z-depth-5" type="submit" name="action">Sign Up</button>
 </div>
</div>
</div>

</form>

 </div>
</div>
 </main>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: This answer to this question is far too long to be answered in a QA format. You clearly need a tutorial. I recommend taking lynda.com's Ruby on Rails 5 Essential Training: https://www.lynda.com/Ruby-Rails-tutorials/Ruby-Rails-5-Essential-Training/500551-2.html?srchtrk=index%3a3%0alinktypeid%3a2%0aq%3arails+5%0apage%3a1%0as%3arelevance%0asa%3atrue%0aproducttypeid%3a2. It will walk you through all the elements of a Rails 5 application.

Comment: @the12 Thank you for replying fast. I will go through the tutorials!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Controllers and Views are linked by default through a common name
Your controller is named like this:

```
users_controller.rb
```

Your views for your controller are all inside a folder called "views" and then inside "users". Usually when you create your controller the views folder is generated with it.

Inside your controller you define methods:

```
def index
end
```

Each method has its own view which has the same name. For example the view for your "index" action, is located in "views" > "users" > "index.html.erb"

In index.html.erb you can write all your html and take whatever you defined in your controller.

For example, let's define the index action and get the index view to show all users:

```
def index
  @user = User.all  # returns an array (list) with all users 
end
```

In your view, @user is a variable you can use to populate the view and you can then do something with it. Let's suppose the user has a name:
index.html.erb

```
<% @user.each do |user|%>  # loop through each user and get the name
  <p>user.name</p>
<% end %>
```

As you can see you view and controller are linked and all you do is really just pass around data.

## **Good things to read:**

Views rendering in RoR:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html

## **Controllers:**

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: Awesome. I am starting to get the hang of it. Thanks a lot!